# how to use functions of other .py modules in a GUI (tkinter) module in the same namespace?

Tags: python

I am new in tkinter please help me out .
I have implemented a module(PDF2Text.Py) that its class has a function (convert_pdf_to_txt(path)) that takes a path of a pdf file and converts the pdf file into text.

I also implemented another module(TopicModeling.py) that its class has a function (creat_LDA_model(text)) that takes a text and do topic modeling on the text.

Now, I want the tkinter GUI that is, upon clicking the "Browse" button it browses the path with filedialog.askopenfilename and its command function send the given path to  convert_pdf_to_txt(path) function of PDF2Text.Py.

Then by clicking the "Model" button, its command function returned text should be sent to creat_LDA_model(text) function in TopicModeling.py and show the result in an Entry widget or any other widget types .

I would like to know the structure of the GUI module; 
how to call or get and set the parameters to other modules/functions from the GUI module in command functions of the buttons.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have multiple questions here. I believe one of them is how to start askopenfilename in a particular folder. Once the file name is returned, i can be passed to another function.

```
fname = askopenfilename(initialdir = r'c:\somepath', filetypes=(("Statement files", "*.pdf"),))
```

To call other functions you have written, import the module, let's cal it ReadPdf.py, use something like this.

```
import ReadPdf
PdfOut = ReadPdf.ReadPDFData(fname)

CCStmtTxns = ReadPdf.ReadPDFData(CreditCardPDFDataPathandFile)
```